# How to log user_name in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, devise

I use Devise in Rails 3. I want to see name of current_user in production.log.

I would like to configure rails like this:

```
config.log_tags = [:user_name]
```

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/roidrage/lograge for this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found this little tricky but working solution.

Warden stores user information in session, but req.session is not available for logging.

So you must add this to config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::Cookies)
config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore)
config.middleware.insert_before(Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore)
config.middleware.insert_before(ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Cookies)
```

Then create file config/initializers/logging.rb

```
Rails.configuration.log_tags = [
  proc do |req|
    if req.session["warden.user.user.key"].nil?
      "Anonym"
    else
      "user_id:#{req.session["warden.user.user.key"][0][0]}"
    end
  end
]
```

Now I see this for Anonymous:

```
[Anonym] Served asset ...
```

and this for user:

```
[user_id:1] Served asset ...
```

Comment: @CharlesBergeron Did you figure out if this approach is ok or not?

Comment: @rit Yep, went with inserting our own custom logging Middleware like this:

`require_relative '../lib/my_app/log_user_id'`

`config.middleware.insert_after(ActiveRecord::SessionStore, MyApp::LogUserId)`

Comment: Be mindful that this approach does not work properly when trying to change your cookie store options. your options will basically be discarded

Answer (score 14):

I used this solution from Wojtek Kruszewski: https://gist.github.com/WojtekKruszewski

I tweaked a little bit for my project to only include id, but basically the same.

```
# config/application.rb

config.log_tags = [
  ->(req){
    if user_id = WardenTaggedLogger.extract_user_id_from_request(req)
      user_id.to_s
    else
      "?"
    end
  }
]
```

And create this initializer

```
# initializers/warden_tagged_logger.rb

module WardenTaggedLogger
  def self.extract_user_id_from_request(req)
    session_key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
    session_data = req.cookie_jar.encrypted[session_key]
    warden_data = session_data["warden.user.user.key"]
    warden_data[0][0]
    rescue
      nil
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 5):

## Added 2013-03-07:

In Rails 4 encrypted_cookie_store is the default session store. This is how you can access session data:

```
session_data = req.cookie_jar.signed[ "_qnaire_session" ]
```

And it looks like warden_data looks differently in my new app, e.g.: `[[542], "$2a$10$e5aYxr/PIp6OOj8jzE7mke"]`, where first item is user id.

Here's my current snippet: https://gist.github.com/wojt-eu/5109643

## Previous version:

This is what I came up with:

```
config.log_tags = [
  :remote_ip,
  ->(req){
    session_data = req.cookie_jar.signed[ "_qnaire_session" ]
    warden_data = session_data["warden.user.provider_user.key"]
    if warden_data
      '#' + warden_data[1][0].to_s
    else
      "guest"
    end
  }
]
```

`_qnaire_session` can be replaced with `instance.config.session_options[:key]` or via singleton: `Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]`

I have ProviderUser model, hence `warden.user.provider_user.key`. I suppose with User model this would be `warden.user.user.key`.

It's messy, but it does not affect normal authentication process, middleware stack order etc. If  it breaks during some update only tagging logs will be affected, which I should quickly notice while looking at development logs.

Comment: Is "qnaire" short for "questionnaire"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm yes (-:

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately log tags are evaluated only once at the very beginning of request delegation (in `Rails::Rack::Logger` middleware). At this stage there is no controller so any current_user helper is not yet available. No warden or even session set up yet, but there is a cookiejar at least, so if you store your session_id there you could restore the session or log session_id instead directly.

```
config.log_tags = [ lambda { |req| req.cookie_jar["_session_id"].to_s } ]
```

I think the best alternative is to store username in the cookie directly at log_in, and destroy it with the session.

```
config.log_tags = [ lambda { |req| req.cookie_jar["user_name"] || 'Noone' } ]
```

NOT WORKING:

But if you use devise, it uses warden raack middleware, so `env['warden']` should be available, so can you try?

```
config.log_tags = [ lambda { |req| user = req.env['warden'].user; user && user.name || 'Noone'; } ]
```

Even without warden, since you do have session available via `env['rack.session']`, if you store user id in session, you can do something like

```
config.log_tags = [ lambda { |req| user = User.find_by_id(req.env['rack.session']['user_id']); user && user.name || 'Noone'; }
```

Comment: Thank's for reply. I tried your first example but it does not work for me. I get "Internal Server Error".

Comment: how about now? channge to req.env

Comment: There is also missing final ']', but I still get "Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I just added to `config/initializers/logging.rb`:

```
Rails.configuration.log_tags = [
  :uuid,   # request UUID
  lambda { |req|
    # Credentials are (currently) in the format of:
    #
    #   <session_hash>::<user_id>
    #
    # So we have to split by '::' to obtain the user_id for logging.
    #
    # This will just output "User: nil" if there is no current session.
    "User: #{req.cookies['user_credentials'].to_s.split('::')[1]}"
  }
]
```

This is for Authlogic. What you need to do might vary, so you should really dig in and see what your data exposes to you already.

Step 1:

See what the `req` object has available. Add this to `config/initializers/logging.rb`:

```
Rails.configuration.log_tags = [
  lambda { |req|
    req.inspect
  }
]
```

Then hit a page, and see what gets dumped.

Step 2: See if your cookie jar has enough information, using the same technique:

```
Rails.configuration.log_tags = [
  lambda { |req|
    req.cookies.inspect
  }
]
```

(hit a request)

An aside: Don't worry about putting in usernames/emails into the logs - user ID is good enough, and you can look it up in the database to get any extra metadata you need.

Comment: Thank's for response. Unfortunately Devise does not use cookies for storing user information.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the cookie decrypter I use in Rails 5.1 to tag the logs with the `user_id`, which is stored in the cookie. It basically lets me access the controller equivalent of `session[:user_id]` from a raw cookie

environments/production.rb:

```
config.log_tags = [
  :request_id,
  :remote_ip,
  lambda do |req|
    session_data = CookieDecrypter.new(req).session_data
    "user_id:#{session_data['user_id']}"
  end
]
```

app/models/cookie_decrypter.rb:

```
class CookieDecrypter
  attr_reader :request

  def initialize(request)
    @request = request
  end

  def session_data
    cookie = request.cookies[session_key]
    return {} unless cookie.present?
    cookie = CGI::unescape(cookie)
    key_generator = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(secret_key_base, iterations: 1000)
    secret = key_generator.generate_key(salt)[0, ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.key_len]
    sign_secret = key_generator.generate_key(signed_salt)
    encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, sign_secret, serializer: JSON)
    encryptor.decrypt_and_verify(cookie) || {}
  end

  private

  def session_key
    Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
  end

  def secret_key_base
    Rails.application.secrets[:secret_key_base]
  end

  def salt
    Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt
  end

  def signed_salt
    Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

And Now for Something Completely Different...

https://github.com/roidrage/lograge/issues/23#issuecomment-11709861

I just tried this with Rails 4, latest Devise and Lograge.

Answer (score 2):

What almost worked for me (Rails 3.2.22.2) is the answer from here: http://benjit.com/rails/logger/2016/02/26/getting-admin-user-into-rails-logfile/

This assumes that the `cookie_jar` object responds to `encrypted`. However it wasn't the case for me. What ultimately worked for me is as follows:

`config/initializers/logging.rb`:

```
Rails.configuration.log_tags = [
  lambda { |req|
    session_key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
    session_data = req.cookie_jar.signed[Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] ]
    warden_data = ( session_data["warden.user.user.key"]|| [[]])
    admin_user = warden_data[0][0]
    "u: #{admin_user || 0}"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @viktortron has said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10813097/316700) at `log_tags` initialization time we have not a proper `session` objet available, but the `session_id` is in the request.

If you are using a _database session_store_, as it is my case, you can rebuild the *session* ad-hoc:

```
session = ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.find_by_session_id(request.cookie_jar["_session_id"])
```

This is how my `log_tags` are defined:

```
# config/initializers/rails_log.rb
def get_user_id(req)
  session = ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.find_by_session_id(req.cookie_jar["_session_id"])
  result = session ? session.data["user_id"] : 0

  "%07d" % result
end

log_tags = []
log_tags << lambda { |req| Time.now.strftime("%F %T.%L") }
log_tags << lambda { |req| req.uuid.first(8) }
log_tags << lambda { |req| get_user_id(req) }

Rails.configuration.log_tags = log_tags
```

The result is something like:

```
[2013-01-22 13:51:36.659] [e52435d1] [0036484] <the log line>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Swards solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117273/518204) and it works like a charm. However using `begin..rescue` instead of Hash#has_key? is a performance killer

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

good_hash = { 'warden.user.admin_user.key' => [[1]]}
bad_hash = {}

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('begin+rescue good hash') { good_hash['warden.user.admin_user.key'][0][0] }
  x.report('has_key good hash') do
    good_hash.has_key?('warden.user.admin_user.key') &&
        good_hash['warden.user.admin_user.key'][0][0]
  end

  x.report('begin+rescue bad hash') { bad_hash['warden.user.admin_user.key'][0][0] rescue nil }
  x.report('has_key bad hash') do
    if bad_hash.has_key?('warden.user.admin_user.key')
      bad_hash['warden.user.admin_user.key'][0][0]
    end
  end

  # Compare the iterations per second of the various reports!
  x.compare!
end
```

Results speak for themselves

```
Comparison:
    has_key bad hash:  4870164.1 i/s
begin+rescue good hash:  3544134.7 i/s - 1.37x slower
   has_key good hash:  2127500.6 i/s - 2.29x slower
begin+rescue bad hash:     4468.2 i/s - 1089.95x slower
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and ugly workaround, maybe one could log a second line after the request has been processed.

This 500 ServerError has been presented by: #{username}

Answer (score -2):

For anyone using Redis::Store @fjuillen's answer looks like this:

```
redis = Redis::Store.new
redis.select 3 # only if you use a different database
result = redis.get req.cookie_jar["_session_id"]
```

tested on rails 4.