# How to print current username to log file in Rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, devise

Recently, I find out tagged logger. It is a very useful option and I config in production environment.

```
# config/environments/production.rb

...

config.log_tags = [ :uuid,:remote_ip ]

...

# log/production.log

[4d23e817-eca8-4db1-ba5b-7456d3af7f65] [127.0.0.1] Started GET "/resources/id" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-26 21:09:11 +0900
```

I also want to print current login user name to log file, so I tried and found a link [How to log user_name in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11102061/3081313).

But It's not working for me.

I'm using devise and rails4. How do I print?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different approach. I've used the following one:

In **application_controller.rb**:

```
before_action: print_current_user

def print_current_user
   if user_signed_in?
      Rails.logger.debug "UserId: #{current_user.id}"    
   end
end
```

Or, you can use the [lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) gem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this is not what I want. I want to prepend current login username to all log like this `[4d23e817-eca8-4db1-ba5b-7456d3af7f65] [127.0.0.1] [chris] Started GET ...`